# Run sbt project in debug mode with a custom configuration

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to introduce a debug mode in my sbt 0.11 project using a special configuration.
I've tried to implement this using the following code but unfortunately, it doesn't seems to work as expected. I'm launching `debug:run` but the run doesn't suspends as expected.

```scala
object Test extends Build {
  lazy val root = Project("test", file("."))
    .configs( RunDebug )
    .settings( inConfig(RunDebug)(Defaults.configTasks):_*)
    .settings(
      name := "test debug",
      scalaVersion := "2.9.1",
      javaOptions in RunDebug += "-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005",
      fork in RunDebug := true
    )

  lazy val RunDebug = config("debug").extend( Runtime )
}
```

Comment: that works when setting javaOptions directly to run configuration : javaOptions in run += "..." but not using my debug configuration

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok that works with the following :

```scala
object Test extends Build {
  lazy val root = Project("test", file("."))
    .configs( RunDebug )
    .settings( inConfig(RunDebug)(Defaults.configTasks):_*)
    .settings(
      name := "test debug",
      scalaVersion := "2.9.1",
      javaOptions in RunDebug ++= Seq("-Xdebug", "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"),
      fork in RunDebug := true
    )

  lazy val RunDebug = config("debug").extend( Runtime )
}
```

now I can run my code in debug mode using `debug:mode`.

Comment: you said, "now I can run my code in debug mode using `debug:mode`".
Did you mean `debug:run`?

Comment: neato. just discovered this question after getting an answer to my related one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437443/how-can-i-make-an-sbt-key-see-settings-for-the-current-configuration

Answer (score 3):

for simply running sbt project in debug mode , just do

JAVA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005

and then

`sbt run` would run SBT in debug mode, you can create a remote debug configuration in eclipse and connect to it.
this is a rather lame, but useful when you have a multi module play project and want to run one of the modules in the debug mode

Answer (score -1):

In Intellij IDEA, I just boot the program in Dedug mode and it seems to work properly without further configuration.