# How can i make an SBT key see settings for the current configuration?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have the following `build.sbt` file:

```
version := "0.0.1"

version in Test := "0.0.1-DEBUG"

name <<= (version) apply { v:String => "demo-%s".format(v) }
```

and while the version seems to be right in the "test" configuration,

```
> show test:version
[info] 0.0.1-DEBUG
```

the name doesn't seem to look at the more-specific setting.

```
> show name
[info] demo-0.0.1
> show test:name
[info] demo-0.0.1
```

This is obviously a greatly-simplified example of what i'm really trying to do, but i think it illustrates the problem/misunderstanding.

**EDIT (2013-07-04)**: What i'm really trying to do is change `javaOptions` in the `IntegrationTest` configuration (b/c we spin up a service and then run testing code against it, and i'd like the service being tested to run in a slightly sandboxed mode). Setting `javaOptions in IntegrationTest` is easy enough (and `show it:java-options` confirms), but doesn't actually get used by `runner` unless i go to the trouble of explicitly defining `it:runner` to use `it:java-options`. I would have expected `*:runner` to prefer the most-specific dependent vars.

Comment: This question isn't particularly encouraging: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845176/how-to-make-a-sbt-task-use-a-specific-configuration-scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your `Build.scala` translated to use `inConfig` as suggested by @MarkHarrah:

```
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._

object DemoBuild extends Build {

  val mySettings = Seq(
    name <<= version { v => "demo-%s".format(v) }
  )

  lazy val demo = Project(
    id = "demo",
    base = file("."),
    settings = Project.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
      organization := "com.demo",
      scalaVersion := "2.10.0",
      version := "0.0.1",
      version in Test <<= version { v => "%s-DEBUG".format(v) }
    ) ++ mySettings
      ++ inConfig(Test)(mySettings)
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for expanding that into a full, runnable example!

Comment: here's a related question that does it with "extend" in a way i'm not sure i understand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104363/run-sbt-project-in-debug-mode-with-a-custom-configuration

Comment: Indeed, `show name` ==> `demo-0.0.1` and `show test:name` ==> `demo-0.0.1-DEBUG` at the sbt prompt!

Answer (score 2):

I tried this in sbt 0.11 and 0.12.1 and it worked:

```
version := "0.0.1"

version in Test := "0.0.1-DEBUG"

name <<= (version) apply { v:String => "demo-%s".format(v) }

name in Test <<= (version in Test) apply { v:String => "demo-%s".format(v) }
```

**UPDATE**

If you're using a Build.scala file you can generalize this task across projects. Here's an example:

```
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._

object DemoBuild extends Build {

  lazy val demo = Project(
    id = "demo",
    base = file("."),
    settings = Project.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
      organization := "com.demo",
      scalaVersion := "2.10.0"
    ) ++ addNameAndVersion("0.0.1", "demo")
  )


  def addNameAndVersion(projectVersion:String, projectName:String):Seq[sbt.Project.Setting[_]] = {
    Seq(
      version := projectVersion,
      version in Test :=  projectVersion + "-DEBUG",
      name <<= version.apply(s => "%s-%s".format(projectName, s)),
      name in Test <<=  (version in Test).apply(s => "%s-%s".format(projectName, s))
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: But then if there was, for example, another key that depended on {{name}}, i would have to override _it_ "in Test" and so forth, for all dependent keys, right?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like you need to upgrade to a Build.scala file. build.sbt is for basic setups, nothing advanced.

Comment: Noah, do you mean you know of a way to express this in a .scala that would behave like i'm looking for? Otherwise, .sbt-vs-.scala seems like a red herring to me. (My real file actually /is/ a .scala; this was just an aggressive simplification.)

Comment: I think you can see from my updated example how you can generalize your settings.

Comment: To make it generalize to many settings, you might put the `name <<= version...` in a method and use `inConfig(Test)(setName)`.  This is the intended way to copy a subgraph of tasks/settings into different scopes.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkHarrah. I have to ask, though, isn't the value of config axes exactly this kind of "dynamic variable"-like behavior?

Comment: The specific problem described in the updated question was fixed for 0.13.0.  The bug was https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/539.  The core feature to enable the fix is called derived settings, which might be what you mean by dynamic variable behavior.  The commit that introduced it is here: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/commit/dfe418b3c3cd64cca3ecfe0df558239dda984943.  It is internal-only now and might stay that way depending on the interactions that pop up.