# How to depend on a setting in the "current" config

Tags: scala, sbt

How can I declare 2 custom sbt settings, say A and B, define B in `Global` config scope with a content that depends on A, define A differently in several config scopes in such a way that the resulting value of B is different in each config even though B is defined only once?

Consider for example `targetHost` below, defined differently in `remote` than in other config, and `scriptContent` depending on it:

```
object MyBuild  extends Build {

    lazy val remote = config("remote") describedAs ("configuration for remote environement ")

    lazy val targetHost = settingKey[String]("private hostname of master server")

    lazy val scriptContent = settingKey[String]("Some deployment script")

    lazy val root: Project = Project("meme", file(".")).
    settings(
        name := "hello",

        targetHost := "localhost",
        targetHost in remote := "snoopy",

        scriptContent := s"""
            # some bash deployment here
            /usr/local/uberDeploy.sh ${targetHost.value}
        """
    )    
}
```

I would like `scriptContent` to have a different value in both config scopes, but since it depends on `targetHost` in the `Global` scope its value is always the same:

```
> scriptContent
[info]
[info]             # some bash deployment here
[info]             /usr/local/uberDeploy.sh localhost
[info]
> remote:scriptContent
[info]
[info]             # some bash deployment here
[info]             /usr/local/uberDeploy.sh localhost
[info]
```

Whereas I'd like to obtain the following:

```
> scriptContent
[info]
[info]             # some bash deployment here
[info]             /usr/local/uberDeploy.sh localhost
[info]
> remote:scriptContent
[info]
[info]             # some bash deployment here
[info]             /usr/local/uberDeploy.sh snoopy
[info]
```

Comment: I guess you need to explicitly specify the scope of  the task. For example, implement two `scriptContent` in both scopes with `targetHost in remote` in one and simple `targetHost` on the other.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! My question is actually a duplicate (sorry...), and the most relevant answer is here: [How can i make an SBT key see settings for the current configuration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17437443/how-can-i-make-an-sbt-key-see-settings-for-the-current-configuration/17479710#answer-17479710)

=> we need to apply the settings multiple times, once for each scope, in order to force the re-evaluation of the content of `scriptSetting`:

```
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._

object MyBuild  extends Build {

    lazy val remote = config("remote") describedAs ("configuration for remote environement ")

    lazy val targetHost = settingKey[String]("private hostname of master server")

    lazy val scriptContent = settingKey[String]("Some deployment script")

    lazy val scriptSettings = Seq(
        scriptContent := s"""
            # some bash deployment here
            /usr/local/uberDeploy.sh ${targetHost.value}
        """
    )

    lazy val root: Project = Project("meme", file("."))
    .settings(
        name := "hello",    
        targetHost := "localhost",
        targetHost in remote := "snoopy"
        )    
    .settings(scriptSettings: _*)
    .settings(inConfig(remote)(scriptSettings) :_*)
}
```

Yields the expected result:

```
> scriptContent
[info]
[info]             # some bash deployment here
[info]             /usr/local/uberDeploy.sh localhost
[info]
> remote:scriptContent
[info]
[info]             # some bash deployment here
[info]             /usr/local/uberDeploy.sh snoopy
[info]
>
```